# Wacom Cintiq Express Key Remote not responding - 16.04

Tags: 16.04, wacom

I have a Wacom Cintiq 27HD Touch. My system is 64bit AMD running Ubuntu 16.04/64 .

The keys on the Express Key Remote do not appear to be sending events for me to re-map.

X is recognising it as existing:

```
xsetwacom list
Wacom Cintiq 27QHD touch Pen stylus id: 9   type: STYLUS    
Wacom Express Key Remote Pad pad    id: 10  type: PAD       
Wacom Cintiq 27QHD touch Finger touch   id: 11  type: TOUCH     
Wacom Cintiq 27QHD touch Pen eraser id: 15  type: ERASER    

@host:/dev/input/by-id# ls -l usb-Wacom_Co._Ltd._ExpressKey_Remote-event-mouse usb-Wacom_Co._Ltd._ExpressKey_Remote-mouse
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Oct  9 10:44 usb-Wacom_Co._Ltd._ExpressKey_Remote-event-mouse -> ../event13
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  6 Oct  9 10:44 usb-Wacom_Co._Ltd._ExpressKey_Remote-mouse -> ../js1
@host:/dev/input/by-id# ls -l ../event13 ../js1
crw-rw-r-- 1 root input 13, 77 Oct  9 10:44 ../event13
crw-rw-r-- 1 root input 13,  1 Oct  9 10:44 ../js1
```

Running xev reports no events from the remote, but does record events from the touch screen, stylus, etc.

X recognises the various key attributes:

```
xsetwacom -s --get "Wacom Express Key Remote Pad pad" "all"
Property 'Wacom Tablet Area' does not exist on device.
xsetwacom set "Wacom Express Key Remote Pad pad" "Button" "1" "key +1 -1 "
xsetwacom set "Wacom Express Key Remote Pad pad" "Button" "2" "+Shift_L +equal -equal -Shift_L "
xsetwacom set "Wacom Express Key Remote Pad pad" "Button" "3" "+3 -3 "
xsetwacom set "Wacom Express Key Remote Pad pad" "Button" "8" "+8 -8 "
xsetwacom set "Wacom Express Key Remote Pad pad" "Button" "9" "+minus -minus "
.
.
.
Property 'Wacom Pressure Recalibration' does not exist on device.
```

Any suggestions on how to get this to work?

Comment: does evtest (run with sudo) show the events? also could you give output of lsb_release -a and uname -a?

Comment: also can you give the output of this command "cd /sys; sudo find . -iname "wacom_remote" | xargs ls"

Comment: sorry last question, has this combination of dongle and Remote ever worked together? (eg. on an earlier Ubuntu, on Windows)

Comment: Last question first - there is no dongle, just the tablet and the remote. When I first started playing with the setup I had events coming through without a problem, but that was several weeks ago, and I'd not worked on it in that time. The host has been rebooted several times in that period, but no OS upgrades.

Comment: xev with sudo does not show the events.

    lsb_release -a && uname -a
    No LSB modules are available.
    Distributor ID: Ubuntu
    Description: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
    Release: 16.04
    Codename: xenial
    Linux enfield 4.4.0-38-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 6 15:42:33 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: cd /sys; sudo find . -iname "wacom_remote" | xargs ls
unpair_remote
@AaronSkomra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a dongle but you might not have noticed it plugged in to a USB port on your Cintiq. It looks like this:

http://www.antcgi.com/Blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/27QHD_USBDongle.jpg

Since you don't have any serial numbers listed in your wacom_remote sysfs directory (

```
cd /sys; sudo find . -iname "wacom_remote" | xargs ls
```

), I can see that the pairing between your dongle and your remote has been broken. There is a way to unpair the remote from the command line (

```
sudo echo * > unpair_remote
```

in the wacom_remote directory), but it is unlikely that you did this. If you use multiple remotes, one remote could "pair over" the pairing of the first remote, but I don't know how the pairing gets lost other than these two methods. FYI the remote has the ability to pair with up to 5 remotes.

Anyway to repair your device follow the instructions at this link:

http://wacom.com/en/support/faqs/cintiq-27qhd-and-cintiq-27qhd-touch/how-do-i-pair-the-expresskey-remote

or use google's cache of those instructions:

http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:DHL00PhaQQsJ:wacom.com/en/support/faqs/cintiq-27qhd-and-cintiq-27qhd-touch/how-do-i-pair-the-expresskey-remote&num=1&client=ubuntu&hl=en&gl=us&strip=1&vwsrc=0

Comment: Perfect! For anyone else watching - it is under the left top cover, assuming you have the drafting stand.

Comment: Url changed: http://www.wacom.com/en-kr/support/faqs/cintiq%2027qhd%20and%20cintiq%2027qhd%20touch/how%20do%20i%20pair%20the%20expresskey%20remote

Answer (score 0):

Since the links provided by Aaron Skomara are dead, I will give the solution I found on a asian wacom site:

- Just connect the remote, place it on the left and press the power switch on it untill it blinks.
- Type `xsetwacom list` in the terminal and the remote shows up!