# How to set up a Cintiq 27QHD Touch on Ubuntu16.04?

Tags: wacom

I need to setup a Cintiq 27QHD Touch to be fully functional with an Ubuntu 16.04 system. What are the steps required to do this?

Regards,
Gecko

Comment: Please specify which drivers you installed and their version numbers. " I have all the drivers..." isn't specific enough. What is the output of 'modinfo wacom'?

Comment: @AaronSkomra - Im not actually sure now if I did install the drivers. Sorry I was not being specific enough, I essentially did not know what to input in my terminal to deliver more information or what exactly is wrong, all I really know is that the tablet can only display the same stuff as my main monitor and can do nothing more. Here is the output for modinfo wacom

Comment: filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-47-generic/kernel/drivers/hid/wacom.ko
license:        GPL
description:    USB Wacom tablet driver
author:         Vojtech Pavlik <vojtech@ucw.cz>
version:        v2.00
srcversion:     464D4A2AF73ACF93E0BCEC0
alias:          hid:b0018g0101v0000056Ap*
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap*
alias:          hid:b0003g*v000017EFp00006004
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap00005002
{I cut some out... }depends:        hid
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-47-generic SMP mod_unload modversions

Comment: @AaronSkomra - Thanks, that worked and restored the functionality of the tablet as a secondary display, but the devices, such as the pen and remote and the touch buttons on the screen are not functional yet, what can I do get those to work?

Comment: @AaronSkomra - I figured out why my devices inputs were not working, the device transfers the data produced by the Wacom pen through a usb cable to the computer. In my case the USB ports were not working, no idea why, but my system does not seem to recognise them, I might have to install additional drivers for my Ubuntu system. Touch functionality produced by ones finger is still not working, neither is my Wacom express key remote.

Comment: It sounds like you have larger problem with your system, you may want to try a fresh install.  RE: The ExpressKey Remote, you may want to see this post once touch is working: http://askubuntu.com/questions/834748/wacom-cintiq-express-key-remote-not-responding-16-04

Comment: @AaronSkomra - Yeah, I agree it is very odd, I think it may have to do with that my motherboard still does not have full linux support in terms of its drivers, not sure. Anyway, thank you for the help, I managed to at least get it to work for pen input which is enough for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you haven't installed the kernel driver. the version would says something more than v2.00 and would be in the "extra" directory.

Detailed instructions for installing the Wacom kernel driver are available at:

http://linuxwacom.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Input-wacom

Comment: Thanks, that worked and restored the functionality of the tablet as a secondary display, but the devices, such as the pen and remote and the touch buttons on the screen are not functional yet, what can I do get those to work?