# How can I use the Wacom Cintiq 27QHD express key remote in 16.04?

Tags: wacom

So it seems someone already asked a similar question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/834748/wacom-cintiq-express-key-remote-not-responding-16-04), but I'm not that computer literate and couldn't understand enough to solve anything.

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, 64-bit. I have a Wacom Cintiq 27QHD; the tablet itself works fine, but the express key remote does nothing.

I was originally using this tablet on a different laptop running Windows 10. Both the tablet and the remote worked perfectly, and there was a Wacom driver UI that allowed me to set what the keys on the remote did. Now on Ubuntu, there is also a UI, but it doesn't have any settings for an express key remote, only for the pen.

If there is a command-line method to do this, I am not familiar with it, and the linuxwacom.sourceforge.net site which I imagine might have this kind of information seems to have been down for a while.

If anyone knows what to do any help would be appreciated, but please try to explain simply so I can understand. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Xorg (not Wayalnd) you can use xsetwacom from the command-line.

The linuxwacom project is being migrated to Github and the wiki pages for xsetwacom are available here:

https://github.com/linuxwacom/xf86-input-wacom/wiki/xsetwacom

https://github.com/linuxwacom/xf86-input-wacom/wiki/Tablet-Configuration-1:-xsetwacom-and-xorg.conf#pad